# How can dynamically filter messages based on content in log4j

Tags: java, logging, log4j, runtime

For example: There is a message "User is logged in Ilmir". How to enable and disable logging of messages containing the word "Ilmir"?

Answer (score 0):

I'd try out their filter mechanism, eg
http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/varia/StringMatchFilter.html

Comment: Thank you!
But with stringmatchfilter can statically specify a condition in log4j.xml how do it is dynamically?